# Adding a condition to modify email content within the same email template in Magento

Tags: php, email, magento

I need to send the same email template for both "pending payment" and "canceled" for **paypal payments**, except that when I notify the customer that they have a **pending payment** it should say `Your order is in pending payment`. If I click **cancel button** in admin, the email content should be `unfortunately your order has been cancelled`.

I have tried this in my mail template:

```
{{if order.getStatusLabel() == 'canceled'}}
 <p>unfortunately your order has been cancelled</p>
{{else}}<p>Your order is in pending payment</p>
{{/if}}
```

But `unfortunately your order has been cancelled` has been sent for both types of order status.

1. My **if condition** Does not seem to be working. Any ideas why not?
2. The **order status** sometimes returns **canceled**, and sometimes it returns **Cancelled**. I'm not sure why it's inconsistent!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use logical operators in email templates. Instead, what you can do is extend the sales order model with a custom method that returns a boolean that will work for you and then call that without a logical operator.